# Get list of disabled products in Magento 2 with SQL query?

Tags: magento2, database, sql

How can I get a list of disabled products in magento 2 using sql query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get entity ids and stores only I used:

```
SELECT entity_id, store_id FROM catalog_product_entity_int
WHERE value = 2 AND attribute_id = (
  SELECT attribute_id FROM eav_attribute
  WHERE entity_type_id=4 AND attribute_code='status'
)
```

Value **2 means disabled**.
Value **1 means enabled**.

You can use following query to get also product names:

```
SELECT t_int.entity_id, t_int.store_id, t_varchar.value FROM catalog_product_entity_int AS t_int
JOIN catalog_product_entity_varchar as t_varchar ON t_varchar.entity_id = t_int.entity_id 
WHERE t_int.value = 2 AND t_int.attribute_id = (
    SELECT attribute_id FROM eav_attribute
    WHERE entity_type_id=4 AND attribute_code='status'
) AND t_varchar.attribute_id = (
    SELECT attribute_id FROM eav_attribute
    WHERE entity_type_id=4 AND attribute_code='name'
)
```

Comment: the sql result is giving different count of collection with admin backend grid collection , I mean if I will filter in backend grid the result is one count and sql is giving another count. I can say there is no pending indexing processor, still don't understand why count is different.
Current magento version is 2.3.3-p1

Answer (score 0):

For Magento 2.2x version, use row_id instead of entity_id in the above sql